# PHP script giving unexcpected $end

Tags: php, html, authentication, dreamweaver

I am getting a weird error in my login script. While through research i couldn't identify the problem. I am wondering if someone can help me thanks. This is the error message,

**Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected $end on line 43.

**code**:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
        header("location:../../login.html");
    }


?>
<?php
    $username = $_POST['txt_username'];
    $password = $_POST['txt_password'];
    if ($username&&$password){

        $connect = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or die("No Server Found");

        mysql_select_db("databse") or die("No Connection");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='$username'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); 

        if($numrows !=0){
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

                $dbusername = $row['username'];
                $dbpassword = $row['password'];
            }
            if ($username == $dbusername && $password == dbpassword) {
                echo "Login Successful. <a href='homepage.html'>Click Here to go to the home page</a>";
                $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
            } elseif ($username == '' || $password == '') {

                die("Please enter a username and password");

            } elseif (empty($dbusername)) {

                die("This account does not exsist");

            } else {
                die("Please enter a username and password");
            }
        }

?>
```

Comment: Did you check your curly brackets?

Comment: Learn to indent your code properly, it makes such problems obvious.

Comment: i have checked my brackets and sorry for indentation when i pasted it in it went all wierd

Comment: "when I pasted it went all weird" -- this is probably because your code has a mixture of spaces and tabs for indenting. You should try to stick to one or the other; don't mix them, because it causes a horrible mess when you load code into a different editor (as demonstrated here). There are code tidying tools that will help you solve this. Also, most decent IDEs (even good text editors) will show you where the missing brackets are and other syntax errors. You should use a good code editor; there are many free ones, so if you aren't, then you're making life harder for yourself for no reason.

Comment: Other : Please note that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and should be avoided. It is strongly recommended to use the PDO library instead.

Comment: Your username should be escaped, otherwise you're vulnerable to hacking. And passwords should *always* be hashed using a decent password library. I recommend [this one](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a closing brace on the last line, to close this if statement:

```
if ($username&&$password){
```

A decent IDE should have picked this up.

You are missing `$` on dbpassword line 28 & need to sanitize `$username`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an ending closing brace of the top most if condition. Your code should be like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
        header("location:../../login.html");
    }


?>
<?php
    $username = $_POST['txt_username'];
    $password = $_POST['txt_password'];
if ($username&&$password){

    $connect = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or die("No Server Found");

    mysql_select_db("databse") or die("No Connection");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE username='$username'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); 

    if($numrows !=0){
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }
        if ($username == $dbusername && $password == dbpassword) {
        echo "Login Successful. <a href='homepage.html'>Click Here to go to the home page</a>";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
             } elseif ($username == '' || $password == '') {

             die("Please enter a username and password");

             } elseif (empty($dbusername)) {

               die("This account does not exsist");

             } else {
                die("Please enter a username and password");
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not close one of the if statements.

```
if ($username&&$password){
```